# query php pagination jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-pagination

I have this sql command that gives me result from search

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE FirstName LIKE '%"
           . $searchText . "%' ORDER by RAND() LIMIT $offset,$per_page");`

can anyone teach me if i can get the number of result so that i can replace the value of pagination this is the value of pagination so it only counts the whole table and numbers of rows.

`$count_query   = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(personid) AS numrows FROM persons");`

I know it will only count all of the rows so it gives me all the result in numbers. I want to   the query so that it will only count the result when I press enter from my search it  is in jquery . can i assign a query that will count the `$query` variable rows result?

Comment: Can you frame your question properly ... not able to understand what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I am getting from your question is that you are trying to count the number of rows returned by first query in $query variable.

`$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);`

This should help you.